# Find memory use order in Android NDK JNI so file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Nearby I noticed that my Android app often crash because of OOM.

I use Android Studio 3.2.3 Profiler, so I find that native heap are up to 300M.

I want to find the memeory use by every C++ so files, BUT I can not find a tool to accomplish my work.

Any advice is appreciated

```
adb shell dumpsys mypackage
App Summary
                       Pss(KB)
                        ------
           Java Heap:    11568
         Native Heap:   202176
                Code:    18576
               Stack:     2716
            Graphics:    84772
       Private Other:    11300
              System:    43414

           TOTAL USS:   331108
               TOTAL:   343727       TOTAL SWAP PSS:    30795
```

Comment: I don't know if/how you can find memory usage per source file (or if that really is useful in trying to solve the OOM problems). But what you _can_ do is use something like AddressSantizer to find memory leaks in your code.

Comment: A good start might be the [Android debug malloc](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/malloc_debug/README.md). That should allow you to get a heap dump of native memory and inspect it, as well as get the callsites where that memory was allocated.

Comment: Alternatively, if you can compile and run the code outside of Android, there are very good memory profiling tools for desktop IDEs. Maybe they can help you identify the memory issue.

Comment: I have read many accounts of "**how to**" on the subject of "**memory usage**" and everyone says it's very complicated. **It is**. *"Usage*" is a problem in itself (**swapping**) The **Java hea**p (and can we extend it) the **Native Heap** (and can we extend it). Images clearly use up much Memory (use S.V.G. ?). The tools don't tell the story, it's a virtual memory system, you don't know what's going on, the OS does, but threading and processes, task deletion.., muddy waters...You would think it would be clear...it is **not**.